# Good e-mail link protection methods

Tags: php, javascript, html, email, encryption

Can you guys post methods of e-mail link spam-protection (in php or javascript)?

Basically I want to put a "mailto" link on a web page, like

`<a href="mailto:pony@fuu.com">E-mail me</a>`

but I don't want the spam bots to pick it up and then spam me with penis enlargement emails :)

So far, I found a javascript obfuscator here: http://www.jottings.com/obfuscator/ Not sure how effective it is though..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/235937/does-email-address-obfuscation-actually-work) and the accepted answer covers a few protection methods and how well they work.

Your best bet is to use CSS code-redirection like so (taken from that link):

> ```
> <span style="unicode-bidi:bidi-override; direction: rtl;">
> moc.elpmaxe@zyx
> </span>
> ```

Comment: I'm going to try the CSS method :)

Comment: Should work in all modern browsers. However, I am not sure if that link will be *clickable*.

Comment: I think you could make it clickable with javascript

Comment: This works for displaying but doesn't work for copying/pasting the text...it ends up backwards

Answer (score 5):

**JavaScript Solution**

With JavaScript you can do the following.

```
emailE = ('yourname@' + 'emailserver.com')
document.write('<A href="mailto:' + emailE + '">' + emailE + '</a>')
```

With this, Crawlers can no longer read your email from source code.

**PHP solution**

With php you can convert your email to unicode values

```
function converte($email) {
    $p = str_split(trim($email));
    $new_mail = '';
    foreach ($p as $val) {
        $new_mail .= '&#'.ord($val).';';
    }
    return $new_mail;
}
```

and on your page use the function like

```
<?php echo converte('my@email.com'); ?>
```

Source code output will be something like

```
&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a PHP function that takes an email, breaks it up, then uses JavaScript to put it back together

```
<?php
function php_split_js_make_email($phpemail)
{
    $pieces = explode("@", $phpemail);

    echo '
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var a = "<a href=\'mailto:";
            var b = "' . $pieces[0] . '";
            var c = "' . $pieces[1] .'";
                var d = "\' class=\'email\'>";
                var e = "</a>";
                document.write(a+b+"@"+c+d+b+"@"+c+e);
            </script>
            <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view emails</noscript>
        ';
    }
?>
```

Demo:
http://djave.co.uk/php-js-email-protector/

Comment: What if JS is disabled? (yes, living in a mad world)